# Typescript + Electron + ThreeJS Import Module converts to require

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, electron

I am building a 3D multiplatform electron app bundled around photoshop with vscode, electron, typescript,electron packager,npm, threejs on windows.

Unfortunately, Typescript works a little against me.
Whenever I compile to js it replaces import {x} from "./y"   with an unnecessary require(y) and some export stuff above it.

This is the index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv= "Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'nonce-a1b2c3d4'"/>
        <style>body {margin: 0;overflow: hidden;} </style>
        <title>CGVERSE 3D</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script nonce="a1b2c3d4" type="module" src="./dist/renderer.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

the tsconfig.json:

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "CommonJS",
            "target": "ES5",
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "removeComments": true,
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "outDir": "dist",
            "baseUrl": ".",
          },
          "include": [ ".node_modules/three/src/**/*.ts","src/**/*","./src/**/*.ts" ]
    }
```

the import part of the typescript renderer.ts:

```
    import * as THREE from "../node_modules/three/src/Three.js";
```

the import part of the compiled renderer.js:

```
    "use strict";
    var __spreadArrays = (this && this.__spreadArrays) || function () {
        for (var s = 0, i = 0, il = arguments.length; i < il; i++) s += arguments[i].length;
        for (var r = Array(s), k = 0, i = 0; i < il; i++)
            for (var a = arguments[i], j = 0, jl = a.length; j < jl; j++, k++)
                r[k] = a[j];
        return r;
    };
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var THREE = require("../node_modules/three/src/Three.js");
```

package.json  adding "type":"module" here did not work.:

```
    {
      "name": "electron-quick-start",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A minimal Electron application",
      "main": "./dist/main.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "watch": "tsc -w",
        "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json",
        "start": "npm run build && electron ./dist/main.js",
        "launch": "npx tsc && electron ."
      },
      "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
      "keywords": [
        "Electron",
        "quick",
        "start",
        "tutorial",
        "demo"
      ],
      "author": "GitHub",
      "license": "CC0-1.0",
      "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^9.1.1",
        "electron-packager": "^15.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
        "typescript": "^3.9.7"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "dat.gui": "^0.7.7",
        "javascript-state-machine": "^3.1.0",
        "require": "^2.4.20",
        "three": "^0.118.3"
      }
    }
```

on a side note, all of it works perfectly if I copy-paste the import from renderer.ts and get rid of all the unnecessary require and export stuff, which I absolutely do not want at all.

To the question. How can I force Typescript to not use requires in modules used in index.html and just use the original typescript import?

Things I tried already after a lot of research on articles, StackOverflow and git repos

```
    -type: module in package.json
    -tsconfig.json ES5, ES6, commonJS, ES3, etc all combinations.
    -require the compiled .js in the .html with no type="module"
    -nodeIntegration: true
```

Comment: I doubt this is the root of the problem, but shouldn't `'commonjs'` in your [TSConfig be all lowercase](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples)? I've also only seen `target: 'es5'` not capitalized.

Comment: I had them lowercase before as vscode was showing me uppercase so I tried that too. 
Unfortunately, it did not help.